# jQuery Flot: Change xaxis when zooming

Tags: flot

Is there a way I can get the x-axis to switch from showing hour, to e.g. week days, months .. when zooming out?

Currently my x-axis is configured as such:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    minTickSize: [1, "second"],
    timeformat: "%H:%M:%S",
}
```

My default the graph looks nice, but when I zoom out enough times, the labels on the xaxis just display "00:00". How can I change the `timeformat` so that the date is included also? E.g. `Tue 27 00:00` or similar.

Here's an example of when the graph is zoomed out a lot (obviously I need to remote some datapoints to make it look smoother..)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a date using the standard specifiers, like %Y-%m-%d.  A full list can be found in the API docs under the [Time Series Data](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) section.

To get the format to update based on the range, i.e. show HMS when zoomed in but YMD when zoomed out, is trickier.  You'll need to listen for the 'plotzoom' event and check the range to see whether the format needs to change.  If so, use getOptions() to retrieve and update the plot's options, then call setupGrid & draw to redraw the plot using the new format.

Comment: So then I just check the difference between say `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`? The part about removing the datapoints: can this we done easilly? I want the point to be there, not just as a circle/dot, because as you see of the image, it does not look good. Thank you very much for replying!

Comment: I did what you said; I called `getOptions` and altered the `xaxis.timeformat` to `%Y-%m-%d` if the difference between `xaxis.min` and `max` was greater than `3600000`. I then called `setupGrid()` and `draw()`, but no labels changed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a custom tickFormatter for the X-axis:

In your xaxis options put:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    tickFormatter: customXAxisFormatter,
    ...
}
```

Then your customXAxisFormatter could be eg. :

```
function customXAxisFormatter(val, axis)
{
    var d = new Date(val);

    // If time difference is more than 24 hours
    if ((axis.max - axis.min) > (24*3600*1000))
        return d.strftime("%a<br>%H:%M");
    else
        return d.strftime("%H:%M");
}
```

I hope this helps :)